# Why was implementation of "Exponent" changed since version 11.3?

Tags: functions, evaluation, version-11.3

I have a following expression and need an exponent of n

```
 Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]]*n^2, n]
 (* 2 *)

 Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]]*n, n]
 (* 1 *)
```

All versions 7,8,9,10 up to 11.0 gives (correctly)

```
 Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]], n]
 (* 0 *)
```

But versions 11.3 and 12.0 returns unevaluated

```
 Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]], n]
 (* Exponent[E^Sqrt[n], n] *)
```

Why this incompatibility ? This expression was a part of my long program and I wasted today lot of time to find why my program not works under higher version of Mathematica. The compatibility is a good thing.

Comment: `0` is not correct because `n^0` usually equals `1`.

Comment: Exponent[n^0,n] is equal to zero. Also Exponent[1, n] is 0.

Comment: Yeah, but asking for the exponent of `n` in  `Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]], n]` does not make sense. Thus, keeping the expression unevaluated is more correct than returning `0`.

Comment: Maybe yes, but question is why was this changed.

Comment: My guess is: Because it is more consistent this way.

Comment: In my program was an expression `Exponent[Exp[Sqrt[n]]*n^k, n]`, where `k` can also be zero - that makes sense.